# absolute centre log-in form hidden bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, authentication, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I am creating a log-in form and trying centre (both horizontally and vertically) the container.

It works perfectly on Desktop and large screen tablets - with the login container perfectly in the centre and with the background image showing as it should.

However on mobile, in portrait view the background picture is not visible and in landscape view i cannot scroll down to fill out the log in form as it gets chopped off.

I have tried fiddling with the size settings but it still doesn't want to work! Heres the Bootply Example:

http://www.bootply.com/NSMhEA6Q43

Answer (score 0):

yes the -50% top margin with fixed position is quirky

this is how i would do it

```
div.container {
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

[fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/QhUd2/)